# Getting modified array output in the form of jsx tags but it won't rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dictionary, jsx

i am new to reactjs, i have been trying to make my own reactjs projects so I came into this strange bug I have in my code. I modified a array of strings on submission of a button using input from a textarea tag. the array changes but I can't see the changes in the form of jsx list. i tried to map over it but it does not work.

```
    import {useState,useRef} from 'react'
    const quotes = ['hi there','greetings']
    const listOfItems = quotes.map((item)=>
      <li key={item}>{item}</li>
    );

    function App() {
      const refrence =useRef()

      function sub (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        quotes.push(refrence.current.value);
        const listOfItems = quotes.map((item)=>
      <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                    );
        console.log(quotes)
        return
        
        
      }
      return (
        <>
        <form onSubmit={sub}>
          <label>type your text here</label>
          <textarea ref={refrence} name='text' type='text' ></textarea>
          <button type='submit'> press me</button>
        </form>
        {listOfItems}
        

        

        
        
        </>
        

        

        
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React will rerender only when you `change state` or when you change `props of component`. you don't do any of that.
to trigger rerender you must store list of components in state and change that

```
    import {useState,useRef} from 'react'


    function App() {
      const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState(['hi there','greetings'])
      const refrence =useRef()

      function sub (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        setQuotes((old)=>[...old, reference.current.value])
        console.log(quotes)

        return
        
        
      }
      return (
        <>
        <form onSubmit={sub}>
          <label>type your text here</label>
          <textarea ref={refrence} name='text' type='text' ></textarea>
          <button type='submit'> press me</button>
        </form>
        {quotes.map((item)=>
      <li key={item}>{item}</li>
     )}
        

        

        
        
        </>
        

        

        
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: thanks, this actually worked. I am quite new to reactjs so I will look more into states but can you explain what you did in setQuotes? you added 3 dots which I think is the spread operator but why?

Comment: because that syntax that i wrote crates new array, which contains all items as old array (spread does his job here) and new value...  its similiar to creating new array as copy of the old one and pushing new value to it, but this one is cleaner and shorter, without temporary variables